# Convert simple ForEach into a Linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

I'm a SQL developer by trade so Linq (and C# in general) is a bit foreign to me, nonetheless I have a simple `foreach` loop that I am thinking might be better served by a Linq query. if nothing else this will be a useful thing to learn even if the problem at hand is not particularly difficult.
Here's my code:

```
bool fireAgain = true;
foreach (var connMan in Dts.Connections)
{
    Dts.Events.FireInformation
        ( 0
          , ""
          , String.Format("Connection Manager {0} has connection string {1}"
          , connMan.Name
          , connMan.ConnectionString)
          , ""
          , 0
          , ref fireAgain
        );
}
```

I can figure out:

```
from connMan in Dts.Connections select connMan
```

easily enough but how do i then pass my connMan into my call to the FireInformation method?

Comment: `nonetheless I have a simple for each loop that I am thinking might be better served by a Linq query`. No I don't think so.`Dts.Connections.ToList().ForEach(connMan=>Dts.Events.FireInformation(.......));`

Comment: linq is generally meant to extract/transform information from a collection/datasource, not to execute logic...so i wonder if using a linq query is the right approach here.

Comment: do use LINQ where it doesn't belong - make life easier to you and your maintainers. LINQ has *query* as last word in acronym, so by default they don't have side effects. In your example this is unavoidable.

Comment: Fair points, thank you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general LINQ would be used to query information. In this case you're also querying the info.

What you could do however is the following:

```
Dts.Connections.ForEach((conMan) =>
{
    Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "", String.Format("Connection Manager {0} has connection string {1}", connMan.Name, connMan.ConnectionString), "", 0, ref fireAgain);
}
```

That is, if Dts.Connections is a List, otherwise you can't do this. (can't tell from your question if it's an IEnumerable or a List)

A workaround would be to create an extension method and the use it anyway. Like this:

```
public void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach(T item in source)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}
```

After that, you can use the ForEach method on your source as shown in the example.

Comment: IEnumerable<T> doesn't have ForEach extension/

Comment: I couldn't tell that from the question. I updated the answer to make it correct for IEnumerable as well.

Answer (score 7):

I would not suggest trying to convert this to Linq, because Linq is meant to be used for functional programming, not imperative. If you wanted to compare it to SQL, then it would be without DML.

`Dts.Events.FireInformation` doesn't seem to return a value that you could select. It probably fires an event or something, and it also uses a `ref` parameter. That piece of code doesn't look like a query at all, and i think it shouldn't be forced into one. A `foreach` loop is perfectly fine in this case, as you're actually doing work inside it and not querying data (which is what linq would be for).

If you needed to filter a collection based on some condition, if you need to join separate collections or something like that, then Linq might be a better tool for the job.

Comment: got, it. Figured that might be the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dts.Connections
   .ForEach(connMan => Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "", String.Format("Connection Manager {0} has connection string {1}", connMan.Name, connMan.ConnectionString), "", 0, ref fireAgain));
```

If Connections is not a IEnumerable, change first line with ;

```
Dts.Connections.ToList()
```

Comment: IEnumerable<T> doesn't have ForEach extension/